# Is there a good standalone Mac application for Python?

Tags: python, macos, sequelpro

I'm just getting into Python coding on my Mac using El Capitan. The main code I use is SQL, which I almost exclusively do through [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com). But as I'm using Python more-and-more (mostly through TextWrangler currently) and I was wondering if anybody knows of a Python-type-version of Sequel Pro? Just in terms of usability and stuff. Sequel Pro is so helpful, and it made learning SQL so much easier a few years back -- it would be great if there was something similar for Python.

Here's a screengrab of Sequel Pro for anyone not familiar:

[image: SequelPro]

Thanks!

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense, quite apart from being off topic. Sequel Pro is a database application, Python is a programming language. What do they have in common?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I think what he's asking for is a Python IDE.

Comment: A Python IDE? In which case the answer is probably [iPython](http://ipython.org).

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry if this question didn't make much sense, but I don't see how it's off topic? I'm asking for an application that would make Python as easy to use as Sequel Pro make SQL easy to use. I don't think that deserves down-votes.

Comment: @DanielRoseman If asking for a tool to help is off-topic, I was unaware -- and I'm happy to close the question.

Comment: @duskwuff Thank you! Based on learning your IDE suggestion, I learned what the proper terminology was and was able to find PyCharm -- which so far seems great. Thanks again for helping!

Comment: @NormanGray Thanks for helping also!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this question in case it's off-topic -- but I found [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) and that seems to be exactly what I was looking for.